# Why do I need to qualify tables with the schema "public" and double-quote some column names?

Tags: sql, postgresql, identifier

I'm a complete beginner to SQL trying to take an online SQL course. I've followed all the directions based on the class video but for some reason my output queries do not look the same as my instructors.

For example, the instructor has:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

And for the query to work for me, I have to write:

```
SELECT * FROM public.table1
```

It seems like I also have to use quotations when calling certain columns in order for the query to work:

```
SELECT * FROM public.table1
WHERE "Column1" IS NULL
```

And when calling columns, have to write:

```
Select Table1.Column1
```

Why is this happening and how to fix it? adding `""` and `public.` to everything makes my code look messy and is a pain in the butt to keep typing over and over. My schema is set to `public`, I'm wondering if that's the issue? Although when I create the table and import from csv, it does not give me any other option except for public.

When I do show `search_path`, it returns:

```
"$user", public
```

Comment: Most likely you got some error messages, I would be handy to share them. Your search path could be different and maybe you created some table or column names using UPPER case. Something you should never do, unless you want some extra work using all the extra quotes "

Comment: Probably your `search_path` isn’t set to `public` so it doesn’t find the tables. And if you create a column that isn’t all lowercase you have to quote it and use correct casing, otherwise it won’t be found either.

Comment: when I do show search_path, it returns:

"$user", public

Comment: `set search_path to public;`

Comment: Regarding the upper case, lower case in the column names, did you use double quotes when creating the table?

Comment: What client are you using to run the queries?

Comment: You need to understand case-sensitivity (or not) of identifiers. See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860 And the role of the `search_path`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860

Comment: For starters, this is not quite true: *"My schema is set to `public`"*